Movie about a timeloop and a crime to be prevented therewith
It's a crime/thriller movie (probably with a time loop theme but not perfectly sure about that). A key scene (I think the movie starts here) is where the main character wakes up in bed in his/her bedroom with a hitman (intruder) on a chair at the foot of the bed. The latter tells the person in the bed he's going to kill him (her?) at a specific time (waiting for orders/phone call). 
There's also a scene on a parking lot with a car. The movie is somewhere between 5 and 10 years old (give or take). I'm almost sure it's a USA production (if it's not, it could be Spanish). It's not a comedy or drama; it's all about the crime, the time loop and the possibilities of preventing the killing.
(sorry for not being able to be more precise. This is the best I can come up with at the moment; I will edit if I have more information)

Are you thinking of Looper? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqLhx4KEX9c

Or Source Code? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxDY6QNg7nQ

No thanks, it's not Looper or Source Code (seen them both). It's a less known and lower budget movie and the scene at the bed is important.

Do you have more informations about the movie: Place? Language? Anything more specific. Feel free to edit your question with the new details (more visible than in comments).

Predestination? I don't remember that kind of scene and it may be too recent, but it could be the movie you are looking for.

Thanks but no, it's not "Predestination". The scene with the hitman at the end of the bed (I'm 99% sure the movie starts with this scene) is information I'm really 100% certain about. So every film without this scene is not the one.

You mention Spanish so that is why I'm mentioning this movie. Is it Los Cronocímenes?
It is a very memorable movie about time travel and a particular crime. In fact, the movie title is literally "Time Crime". It was made in Spain. It features an assassin (of sorts, I won't give spoilers) and, it is about trying to stop him. It is from 2007, so it is in your specified time frame (pun). And like all of these time travel thrillers, the time loop is a key plot element.
A car does feature prominently also, but I can't be certain about a character waking up to see the killer in his bedroom. But there is this mysterious threat of death at a certain time.

This is a great film, but there is no event of a killer at a bed in this one ..

Thanks but no, it's not "Timecrimes". The scene with the hitman at the end of the bed (I'm 99% sure the movie starts with this scene) is information I'm really 100% certain about. So every film without this scene is not the one.

I think this is Minority Report (2002). The movie is about police officer that can arrest crime before they committed to do it. It was quite controversial, since the criminal is arrested for a crime that not executed yet. source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority_Report_%28film%29

Well, Minority Report could be confused with Time Travel.

Nope. It's not minority report. No scene in there like the one I described.

Shot in the dark, but are you thinking about Memento? It shares similar things with what you described if I recall correctly.

There are no timeloop in Memento

@Nick There is still no need to get agressive and insulting. Be it only a guess, a little elaboration of why you think this film fits to the details from the question could still help to flesh out this answer a little more.
